# Firemonkey OSX update progressbar during download

Tags: macos, delphi, progress-bar, indy, firemonkey

The progressbar being updated is shown in Windows. In OSX the progressbar is shown but without see the progressbar shifting.

See code below.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  m : TMemoryStream;
begin

   IdHTTP1.OnWork:= HttpWork;
  m := TMemoryStream.Create;

  IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.example.com/pictures.zip', m);

  m.SaveToFile('/users/demo/pictures.zip');
  m.Free;

end;

procedure TForm1.HttpWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCount: Int64);
var
  Http: TIdHTTP;

  ContentLength: Int64;

  Percent: Integer;
begin
  Http := TIdHTTP(ASender);

  ContentLength := Http.Response.ContentLength;

  Percent := 100 * AWorkCount div ContentLength;

  ProgressBar1.Value := Percent;

end;
```

How can the progressbar be updated in OSX?

Comment: Is the HttpWork handler being called? If not then it's an issue with the HTTP components rather than the progress bar, and you may get a better answer by restating your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I have in my code, and it works on both Windows and Mac:

```
Percent := 100 * AWorkCount div ContentLength;
frmDownloadProgress.ProgressBar1.Value := Percent;
Application.ProcessMessages;
```

`Application.ProcessMessages` is the key for updating the progress bar if the TIdHTTP component is on the main thread.

Comment: +1 but something like "use TIdHTTP in a separated thread and ask it every so often what's the progress" would have been a good advice (:

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does Application.ProcessMessages also work under OSX?

Comment: @Mike, yes, `Application.ProcessMessages` works cross platform.